# I want to develop own custom SDK in react native project

Tags: react-native, sdk

I want to develop own custom SDK in react native project and i want to use that SDK in another react native project. are there any steps to create. pls help me with this.

I have searched on google but didn't find any proper solution or steps.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is general, it is very good starting to have stable/nice architecture if you have multiple api calls/functions that will be used in multiple clients(web/apps)

That's possible and very convenient indeed. Benefits would be using same sdk functions across multiple apps/web included. When you want to integrate the sdk with web such as react/etc make sure packages are supported both in app/web.

First, you need to create private/public repo in github and implement functions/api calls as exportable classes.
Later, you need to publish them as npm package and use in multiple apps/web